# Cannot connect to http://dlinkap to configure wifi router

Tags: wireless-router, internet-connection, website

I should configure my wifi router PowerLine AV 500 Wireless N Mini Starter Kit but when i searche in internet http://dlinkap it redirects me to http://ww8.dlink.com. 
The first time I tried it worked but now i can't and I want to know where and what is the issue.

Comment: You may want to give `http://dlinkap/` (note the trailing slash) a try. Trailing slashes are often required to suppress automatic searches for local addresses in modern versions of Chrome/Firefox. That said, some devices do redirect local requests to non-local pages to test internet connectivity or for other reasons.

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Can you please paint this with more words? PowerLine AV 500 Wireless N Mini Starter Kit is not a Wifi Router. It is a wired and wifi extender.
Are you trying to configure a device to use the extended wired connection? Or the wireless? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: Try `http://dlinkapWXYZ.local` or `http://192.168.0.50`. If those don't work, try using `ipconfig` or `ifconfig` to find your default gateway IP and use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could happen if you have changed your ip-ranges but the link hasn't been updatet.

-open the "command prompt",

-type "ipconfig",

-find your ip-range i.e. 192.168.0.23.

-try http://192.168.0.1 on your browser or reinstall the "router".

most routers use xxx.xxx.xxx.1

almost like Worthwelle wrote before

hope it could help

busy

Answer (score 0):

I hope you figured out how to do this by now, but just in case you haven't, I had the same exact problem and I found a surefire way to get into the config page:

1. get into your router config page:
   for me (linux) I typed into a terminal:

   ```
   ip r | grep default
   ```

   which gave me my router IP:

   ```
   192.xxx.xx.1
   ```
2. after using that IP in my browser, in the router config page, I found the powerlink device, by clicking on "details" I got the IP:

   [image: router config page with powerlink details]

   As you can see it is connected to the third LAN port, and the IP is highlighted.
   **type that IP into your browser, you should get the powerlink config page**

I hope this helps someone somewhere.